hono cloudflare work - environment variable in vitest
Using Hono to create a Cloudflare Worker, how can I read environment variables when using vitest ?  The below works with wrangler dev but fails when I use vitest:
[GET] http://localhost:8787/blackholesun
--> GET /blackholesun 500 3ms
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FOOBAR')


import { Hono } from "hono";


type Bindings = {
  FOOBAR: string;
};

const app = new Hono<{ Bindings: Bindings }>();


app.notFound((c) => {
  console.log("[!] foobar: ", c.env.FOOBAR);
  return c.text("page not found", 404);
});

The unit test:
    describe("test basic routes", () => {
      ....
    
      it("check 404 returned ok", async () => {
        const blackholeReq = new Request("http://localhost:8787/blackhole", {
          method: "GET"
        });
        const res = await app.request(blackholeReq);
        expect(res.status).toBe(404);
      });
    });

More details:

When the test starts I get the expect output: Using vars defined in .dev.vars.
Others have suggested to go against the docs and use a .env file.
I tried vi.stubEnv with no success.


The answer was found in a new Hono article about vitest and Cloudflare workers here.  I had missed import { env } from 'cloudflare:test'.
// src/index.test.ts
import { env } from 'cloudflare:test'
import app from './index'

describe('Example', () => {
  it('Should return 200 response', async () => {
    const res = await app.request('/hello', {}, env)   # INFO - env added here

    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
    expect(await res.json()).toEqual({
      hello: 'world',
      var: 'my variable',
    })
  })
})

Another example was here.
